# Plotting Confidence Bands for a Single Variable?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

Is it sensible to plot the upper and lower 95% Confidence Bands when you want to visualize the effect of a single variable on Y?

For example, in **multiple** linear regression you would plot a line for extpected change in Y due to a coefficient. And you would plot the upper and lower confidence bands, which are straight lines, too.

I haven't found a book or artikle where such aplot has been used. Thats why I am confused whether you are allowed to plot the upper and lower confidence intervals.

Comment: The idea behind the plot is to visualize how one single variable affects the dependent variable. So, on the Y-axis there is the expected change in Y for a specific value of x. I am not sure if it is neccessary to fix the other variables because I am not interested in the real value of Y. I am just interested in how much Y increases due to an increase in x.

Comment: It really only seems to make sense to do this, I think:  plot 1 regression line with all variables fixed and then include 95% confidence interval for the mean response as you normally do.  Then plot another regression line with all variables fixed, but the one variable's value fixed at the new level and this revised regression along with the plotted 95% confidence interval of the mean response.

Comment: You could also just plot your estimated coefficient and then draw a bar around it to illustrate the standard error of that coefficient, depending on what you are really after here.  See here for example:  http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/coefplot/getting-started.html